# Notification of media inserted to DVD tray in FreeBSD

Tags: script, dvd, freebsd

I would like to create a script that automatically copy the dvd to a folder in my FreeBSD box (copy back DVD archives). 
I would need a notification from the system when the DVD tray has been closed. I haven't found any start point which subsystem should provide this. I was look for hal, but I can't see how can it help me.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the sysutils/automount port.

It's config file has a parameter FM where you could launch your script.